# Unknown error: Error: No valid exports main found for src\main\ui\node_modules\uuid?

Tags: angular, npm-install

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLFap.png)i reinstall npm and i have this issue:Unknown error: Error: No valid exports main found for 'D:\travail\optimus\src\main\ui\node_modules\uuid'
Angular cli v 1.7.3
Node v 13.6

Comment: Unknown error: Error: No valid exports main found for 'D:\travail\optimus\src\main\ui\node_modules\uuid'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! ui@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ui@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PPP-IT02\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-10T10_56_11_968Z-debug.log

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I know that **Nodejs** version v13 had some issues.
Use  **v12.16.3** and it's working.
Either use latest **v14.2.0** or official **LTS v12.16.3**

Comment: I istalled node v14.2.0 and when i try to launch (npm start) i have this error: The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.

Comment: and when i try to update my project : Repository is not clean. Please commit or stash any changes before updating.

Comment: If my answer works for you, please accept the answer.